# Notify Daily of Answers

Tags: support

Maybe it's just me but when you check that option and give an email address, I don't then see a button or anything to solidify that setting.  There is no save or anything.  Am I missing something?  If I just check that checkbox and give an email, I have not submitted this setting and I don't see a way to submit it.

Comment: It's not just you. That UI could use a bit of a polish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your settings are saved as redsquare has pointed out.  It's all done via immediately via AJAX so there's no need to confirm the change.

Comment: Oh yes there is a need to confirm this! When someone comes here and asks (or, like me, googles) to see how to use a simple checkbox with a textarea - then the UI design has fallen flat on its face.

Comment: ok that's fine but this is not very good usability.  Users even us devs expect some kind of indication something happened.  And as we know developers are not usability experts...your customers input is how you test usability.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is one for the future however it should be hidden to avoid confusion!

Actually I tell a lie, as soon as you check the input it sends an ajax request to update the setting. Not really the best user experience as there is no notification and its not the normal way to save settings. Two of us have been confused already.