# "Notify <e-mail> daily of any new answers" doesn't provide visual feedback

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-interface, usability

When checking/unchecking the "Notify  daily of any new answers" on a question that has already been asked, there is nothing to give the user feedback that the check has been registered. An AJAX event is fired to store the check, but the user doesn't realize that and goes looking for some kind of submit button, or maybe realizes it is AJAX but doesn't know if it was successful.

Typically, some kind of "working..." animation would display beside the field when the Ajax event is fired, and upon completion it would either disappear or be replaced with a green check icon or text saying something like "setting stored".

---

Note: I found at least two support requests on MSO from users confused by this:

- [Notify Daily of Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10704/notify-daily-of-answers)
- [how to use email notification after question is posted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24254/how-to-use-email-notification-after-question-is-posted)

Comment: Sigh... what a godawful UI experience - and declined with no argumentation whatsoever.

Comment: @romkyns If the status was deferred, the bounty would make sense, but I highly doubt a status-declined more then a year ago will be looked at again because of a bounty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like Shog9 said...

[Visual Feedback http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/365/sonotifysuccess.jpg](http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/365/sonotifysuccess.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow doesn't *believe* in pansy HTML feedback gadgets. We're *programmers*, man - if you really want to know if it succeeded, just watch for the response packets in Wireshark!

Comment: hilarious!!!!!!